# Bundle does not work with custom route mvc 4

Tags: model-view-controller, bundle, canonical-link

I've created custom route to support canonical url. It works on the local system. However when I tested my code onto server the bundle created a link but couldn't render the css and js.

Here's the code

```
    routes.MapRoute
    (
        "Custom",
        "{*catchAll}",
        new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    ).RouteHandler = new CustomRouteForSlugs();


    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

The link it created on the production link is:

```
    <link href="/Content/css?v=WMr-pvK-ldSbNXHT-cT0d9QF2pqi7sqz_4MtKl04wlw1" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=rGcoDow97GYrNMSwHq7xCCjlcB3UIY4_OhPRc6BBSQA1"></script>
```

While checking it over the firebug, I'd seen no script or js code attached to it. Putting back a link to static file for css or js works.

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: I'd solved the problem by adding the scripts and styles to routes.IgnoreRoute("bundles/{*pathInfo}").